# pyspark : AnalysisException when reading csv file

Tags: pyspark

I am new to pyspark . I am migrating my project to pyspark . I am trying to read csv file from S3 and create df out of it. file name is assigned to variable cfg_file and I am using key variable for reading from S3. I am able to do same using pandas but get AnalysisException when I read using spark . I am using boto lib for S3 connection

```
df = spark.read.csv(StringIO.StringIO(Key(bucket,cfg_file).get_contents_as_string()),  sep=',')
```

AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: file: